# Determining if an array contains an even number

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and am trying to get a feel for the language. Here's a function I wrote which is supposed to return true if an array contains an even number and false if it does not.

```
var containsEvenNums = function(numArray) {
    numArray.forEach(function(element) {
        if(element % 2 == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    return false;
};

var main = function() {
    var nums = [1,2,3,4];

    console.log("This array contains even number(s): " + containsEvenNums(nums));
};
```

I know that this has something to do with AJAX and callback functions, but since I'm new to the language, can you explain why exactly my code is returning "undefined"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't save anywhere the fact that there is an even number in your array.

## You could do this

```
var containsEvenNums = function(numArray) {
    var containsEvenNum = false;

    numArray.forEach(function(element) {
        if(element % 2 == 0) {
            containsEvenNum = true;
        }
    });
    return containsEvenNum;
};
```

But this method has a disadvantage: it needs to loop through the entire array (you can't break).

## I'd recommend using [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead

```
var containsEvenNums = function(numArray) {
    return numArray.some(function(element) {
        return element % 2 === 0;
    });
};
```

Comment: Why do you have to return the numArray.some()? Why isn't the return statement in the call back function enough?

Comment: Because otherwise when you call `containsEvenNum()` you will get `undefined`, it needs to be relayed. Just like you would do, let's say you need to get some data from point a to point c, going through point b. Point b needs to also carry the data to point c, otherwise c will not have it, which means data is lost during its travel.

Answer (score 1):

The `main()` method is  returning falsy value because inside `forEach` it's checking for each value of array and then the final statement `return false` is run. The loop is not stopped on first match.

If you had used normal `for` loop it would have worked fine.

You may either use a `var flag = false;` in your function. Inside your forEach loop set the flag if even number is present. return that flag.

Else i would prefer:

```
var containsEvenNums = function(numArray) {
    return numArray.some(function(value) {
       return value % 2 ==0;
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I know that this has something to do with AJAX and callback functions,

No, it doesn't; [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) is generally a pattern describing the usage of the asynchronous call with [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

Your issue could be probably more related to [Functional Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming), where you have first class functions.

In your specific case, you have two anonymous function: the first one, is assigned to `containsEvenNums`, and the second one is given as argument of `forEach`. Your `return` statement is inside that one, so `containsEvenNums` doesn't have a `return` statement, therefore it returns always `undefined`.
Plus, [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is not suggested here, because you iterate over all the array's item anyway, so if your scenario is knowing if the array contains at least one even number, is suboptimal.

You could definitely set a variable if you find an even number:

```
var containsEvenNums = function(numArray) {
  var containsEven = false;  

  numArray.forEach(function(element) {
    if(element % 2 == 0) {
      containsEven = true;
    }
  });

  return containsEven;
};
```

But as said, is suboptimal. You want probably stop as soon as you find an even number, so probably [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) is what you're looking for:

```
function isEven(number) {
  return number % 2 === 0;
}

function containsEvenNums(numArray) {
  return numArray.some(isEven);
}
```

As you can see, the advantage of a little more functional approach, is that you have more generic predicate functions. In that case, `isEven` can be used as stand-alone function, for single value:

```
if (isEven(userInput)) { ... }
```

Or for other Array's methods:

```
// every item of the array has to be even
var result = numArray.every(isEven)
```

Or for [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition_%28computer_science%29).